# What are the advantages and disadvantages of SharePoint Portal Services (SPS) over SharePoint Team Services (STS)?

Tags: sharepoint

I do not know clearly the merits and demerits of SPS and SPT. I was searching in google too for the past one week, but could not. Can anyone help?

Comment: Actually SPS/STS are from the 2001 era - the version of SharePoint that everyone has forgot and with good reason ;)

Answer (score 3):

This post will give you the correct terminology to use for the different editions and versions :-

[SharePoint Versions through the ages – Confused?](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2010/06/sharepoint-versions-history/)

[image: SharePoint Versions]

To compare the features of different versions :-

- [SharePoint 2010](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/Pages/Editions-Comparison.aspx) - Foundation / Server / Enterprise
- [SharePoint 2007](http://www.milesconsultingcorp.com/SharePoint-Portal-2007-Version-Comparison-between-MOSS2007-and-WSS3.aspx) - WSS 3.0 / MOSS 2007
- SharePoint 2003/2001 - Really? Time to upgrade ;)

Answer (score -1):

I know only the merits of SPS and STS, so i have given it below. Let me give you some other time demerits. Let you check the merits of it here. Let me know for any clarifications.

SharePoint Portal Services (SPS) has MUCH better document management. It has check-in, check-out, versioning, approval, publishing, subscriptions, categories, etc. STS does not have these features, or they are very scaled back. SharePoint Portal Services (SPS) has a better search engine, and can crawl multiple content sources. STS cannot. STS is easier to manage and much better for a team environment where there is not much Document Management going on. SPS is better for an organization, or where Document Management is crucial.